# Update single value in ruby hash from super

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing tests in RSpec and am trying to declare some variables with `let`:

```
describe 'my_test' do
    let(:params) {{
        :happy => 1,
        :sad => 0,
    }}

    context 'mixed' do
        let(:params) {{
            :happy => 1,
            :sad => 1,
        }}
    end
end
```

But then I saw how variables can be overwritten with `super`, which would be convenient for long lists of params: https://rspec.info/blog/2013/02/rspec-2-13-is-released/

So my question is: how do I overwrite just a single value in the original hash? I've tried searching but can only find ways to overwrite all values. Does anything like the below exist?

```
let(:hash) { super().updatehash('sad', '1') }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can overload hash variables using Hash#merge

```
let(:hash) { super().merge(:sad => '1') }
```

it will overwrite any key-values in the original hash with the key-value pairs you provide in the hash to merge over it.

If you'd like a link to the doco for merge, apidock is good:

http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge

Comment: That'll be great, as I'm pretty new to ruby and rspec and am not exactly sure where to look up stuff

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!!